# Как спарсить изображения из этого json файла

Tags: android, json, парсер

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Title": "Russis",
    "Link": "aaaa",
    "PubDate": "2016-03-20T00:00:00",
    "Image": "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/russia.png"
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Title": "aa",
    "Link": "aaa",
    "PubDate": "2015-02-06T00:00:00",
    "Image": "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/russia.png"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject item = array.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.d("TAG", "Image: " + item.getString("Image"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```